# Hosting games locally with Flash?

Tags: flash, networking, browser, actionscript

I just can't find the right Google search terms for this...

Is it possible to use Flash (or a Flash compatible service) to allow players in a game to host their own games (using their own bandwidth), through a web browser? In a way, to run their own  game servers (for a Flash in-browser game) from their computer, but through a web browser using Flash?

If so, any recommendations?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to make some kind of "game room" on which users can join local sessions hosted by themselves.

The word you are looking for is P2P.

Some useful links:

- http://www.flashrealtime.com/local-flash-peer-to-peer-communication-over-lan-without-cirrus/
- http://www.flashrealtime.com/video-on-demand-over-p2p-in-flash-player-101-with-object-replication/
- http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html
- http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_apps_cirrus_lccs.html

Cheers

Comment: Yep RTMFP seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Though it seems to have some connectivity problems (NAT punchthrough) from what I can see.

Comment: RTMFP is merely the protocol used by Flash to enable P2P :)
P2P is the general term for the kind of architecture you are trying to achieve. Glad to point you in the right direction then.

Answer (score 1):

Flash has [flash.net.ServerSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) class, which can listen to incoming connections. So it's certainly possible, but I doubt it scales well beyound several players.