# Design Issue: Action Script Community Driven Server Hosting and Game Lobby

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, real-time

I want to create a 2D real time multiplayer game in the browser in Action Script that can do the following:

Client:

> Player logs into Account via Flash Client.
>
> Player hits 'Versus Mode' Button.
>
> A lobby with a list of online servers come up.
>
> Player joins game.

Heres where the problem comes in, I want the servers to be community hosted. i.e. the player downloads and runs a server app on their own desktop for other players to join. Players then go to the website and access the browser based client to find a list of active servers.

This would be a commercial product (players buy an account to log in through the client) and each player hosted server must handle 20 live players. As the servers are not centralized and scalability is handled by the community typical solutions like SmartFoxServer licences will not work.

Architecture Overview:

> I have a server with Account details, DB List of Servers, the Client and a downloadable
>   Server App.
>
> The Player Downloads the Server App and runs it.
>
> The Server App points to my server and is added to the list of worlds
>   available in the lobby.
>
> Players access their account through the Client and joins one of the Player hosted Servers to
>   play.
>
> Design Note: any State about the Players progress is held on a per Server basis. The Client and my server are only concerned in verifying the Player Account.

How would I go about creating this game lobby? What could I use to create the Server App? Does AS have any built in libraries to handle this? I want to keep things as simple as possible.

I have experience in AS3, Java 7 and PHP 5.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will always need a centralized server which handles player login requests and game room lobby.
You can probably use any technology for this as long, since the AIR client can connect to your server via RPC/Webservice/RestService.

As for the client side game hosting, I believe the word you are looking for would be P2P.
There are ways to achieve P2P in flash/flex.
http://www.flashrealtime.com/basics-of-p2p-in-flash/
 
Is a fine resource to get started with that.

Also see
[Hosting games locally with Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249516/hosting-games-locally-with-flash/6250703#6250703)